# next text wrap and add text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do not know how to put text into strong and add "x".

```
<span>something</span> 5 
<span>something</span> 4
```

And I want:

```
<br /><span>something</span> <strong>5x</strong>
<br /><span>something</span> <strong>4x</strong>
```

My solution:

```
$("span").each(function() {
    $(this).before("<br />");
    $(this.nextSibling).wrapAll("<strong></strong>").after("x");    
});
```

But the output is not perfect:

```
<br /><span>something</span> <strnong>5 x</strong>
<br /><span>something</span> <strnong>4 x</strong>
```

How to remove blank between 5 and x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$("span").each(function () {
    $(this).before("<br />");
    $(this.nextSibling).wrapAll("<strong></strong>").parent().text(function (i, t) {
        return t.replace(/\s+$/, '') + 'x'
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GWRX3/)

Comment: You can also [use `.trim` to remove the new lines](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/f8qjk/) at the end. :)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 but it will remove the leading space also... may not be what OP wanted - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GWRX3/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny - You can always add it back at the end though.

Answer (score 0):

You can select each `strong` element using `$('strong').each()` and then use `$(this).replace(/ /g,'')` to strip the spaces.